# Search MariaDB with stop words in query expansion mode

Tags: sql, mariadb

With MariaDB, one of the words in my stopwords file is "how". After setting up a fulltext index on column1, and doing a natural language query search, no results are returned. This is good.

```
select count(*) from myTable where match (column1) against ('how' in natural language mode)
0 results
```

When using query expansion, results containing how are returned. This is something I do not want in our application.

```
select count(*) from myTable where match (column1) against ('how' with query expansion)
+1,000,000 results
```

Is there a way to do a search with query expansion with stop words?

**Edit**

The engine being used in myTable is MyISAM. The `show indexes in table_name` command show that column1 of myTable is setup as a fullindex.

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type  Comment  Index_comment
MyTable 0           PRIMARY   1             column1      NULL       1            NULL      NULL    YES    FULLTEXT
```

Here is a screen shot showing I am able to reproduce the issue with the actual database.

[image]

Here is the output of `show variables like 'ft%'`

```
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len = 84
ft_min_word_len = 3
ft_query_expansion_limit = 20
ft_stopword_file = /var/www/stopwords
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me.  The first query should be returning no results.  Hence there should be no words for the expansion.

Comment: "Note

Because blind query expansion tends to increase noise significantly by returning nonrelevant documents, use it only when a search phrase is short".... source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html looks to me query expansion did indeed return alot nonrelevant records.

Comment: Stopword list does not apply to searches with the like operator. So, the whole situation is strange.

Comment: I have removed the non-fulltext search using the like operator from my example, since our table is fulltext, so that we do not get hung up on the like operator example.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, if you want to post a suggestion to issue a bug to the MariaDB team, I am happy to accept your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour. If the search with the like does not return any results, that means the searched string (substring...) is not there in any of the rows. Ran the fulltext search with query expansion on mariadb and it did not return any hits - just as expected. Pls add sample dataset, exact mariadb version, and table type that would enable us to reproduce the behavior. In this format this question just makes an unverifiable claim that sg is wrong with mariadb's fulltext search.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @Shadow - I have edited my question with more detail.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft%'`;

Comment: I added the output of `show variables like 'ft%'`